# Dynamic file loading in jetty

Tags: webserver, jetty

As per our implementation we are dynamically creating some image files in the server side and sharing the URLs.
But we are unable to retrieve the image resources using the URLs if the file is created while the JETTY is running.

However we can retrieve it if we stop the jetty and start it again.

I would like to know if there is any configuration which will enable us to retrieve the resources  without the jetty being stopped?

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to persist the dynamic images? If not, you can just stream the dynamic image like this:

```
    public void sendImage(RenderedImage image, String mimeType, String imageIOType, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        if(image != null)
        {
            OutputStream output = null;
            try
            {
                output = response.getOutputStream();
                response.setContentType(mimeType);
                ImageIO.write(image, imageIOType, output);
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(output != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        }
    }
```

HTH