# Loading dynamically created files in Jetty

Tags: jenkins, jetty

I have a question similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294867/dynamic-file-loading-in-jetty):

I'm maintaining a custom Jenkins plugin. While migrating to the latest Jenkins (v1.586) from a rather old version we encountered a problem caused by Jenkin's change from Winstone to Jetty:

The plugin is creating image files at runtime (i.e. names and content are dynamic), which are linked from HTML. I can see those files in the webroot directory, but accessing them via a browser results in a 404. As it seems, Jetty only recognizes files known at startup time.

My question: Is there any way to make Jetty allowing access to files created at runtime? If not, what's the best alternative (under the assumption we'd like to avoid having to patch Jenkins, of course)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this plugin open source?  Can you post the code where you determine the webroot location and then write out the file?

Comment: It's closed source, so I can't post any code, I'm afraid. The webroot location is a fixed path set as a constant in the plugin, and set at Jenkins start via --webroot.

Comment: traditionally, a servlet webroot is where the server initializes from, not where its live environment is.

Comment: Can I define such live environments without changing the Jenkins war, i.e. via command line? Or in other words, given a running Jenkins, where to put such content?